# Powershell script to delelte items older than 3 months from first stage recycle bin in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, search-results

Below script deletes All Recycle Bin items in SharePoint 2007.
Wanted help to modify the script to delete only items older than 3 months.

=============================================

```
$sitecollectionUrl = "http://domainname.com/sitecollectionurl"
$siteCollection = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($sitecollectionUrl)
write-host("Items to be deleted : " +$siteCollection.RecycleBin.Count.toString())
$now = Get-Date 
write-host("Deleting started at " +$now.toString())
$siteCollection.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();
$now = Get-Date
write-host("Deleting completed at " +$now.toString())
$siteCollection.Dispose();
```

=============================================

Comment: When you say "items" older than 3 months, do you mean List Items, as in only items deleted from a SharePoint List? Or do you mean any object that's been in the Recycle Bin for more than 3 months. up to & including sub-sites, lists, libraries, folders, documents & list items?

Answer (score 1):

This script will accomplish the goal, at least in SP2010/2013/2016. I don't have access to an SP2007 box but you should easily be able to replace my use of the Get-SPSite cmdlet with the new-object sytnax.

```
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://YourHostName.net/sites/YourSiteCollection"

# Set this to any positive integer; items more than this many days old will be deleted
$DaysOldToDelete = 90

# This only deletes items deleted from an SP List or Library; tweak or remove the $_.itemtype filter as needed
$SPRecycleBinItems = $SPSite.RecycleBin | where { $_.itemstate -eq "FirstStageRecyclebin" -and $_.DeletedDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysOldToDelete) -and ($_.itemtype -eq "ListItem" -or $_.itemtype -eq "File")}
foreach ($ItemToDelete in $SPRecycleBinItems) {
    $ItemGUID = new-object system.guid($ItemToDelete.ID);
    $SPSite.RecycleBin.Delete($ItemGUID)
}
$SPSite.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi Stevangelista.. Thanks so much for the quick response.
I meant deleting any object that's been in the Recycle Bin for more than 3 months

Comment: No problem; per the inline comment, you can just remove the `$_.itemtype` conditions from the where clause and it will delete anything & everything in the Stage One Recycle Bin that's older than the number of days your `$DaysOldToDelete` variable is set to.